# Determine if type is Option[_] in scala compiler plugin

Tags: scala

How can I determine whether a Tree object is a subtype of `Option[_]` in a scalac (2.11) plugin?

Example:

```
    class OptionIfPhase(prev: Phase) extends StdPhase(prev) {
      override def name = OptionIf.this.name
      override def apply(unit: CompilationUnit) {
        for (tree @ Apply(TypeApply(Select(rcvr, TermName("map")), typetree), List(param)) <- unit.body;
             if rcvr.tpe <:< definitions.OptionClass.tpe)
          {
            reporter.echo(tree.pos, s"found a map on ${rcvr} with type ${rcvr.tpe} and typelist ${typetree} and arg $param")
          }
      }
```

This if-guard is always false, unfortunately. If I remove it completely, it matches all "typed" maps (as expected). Here's a few examples of expressions that I would like to match:

```
// All of these maps
val x = Some(4).map(_ * 2)
val xo: Option[Int] = x
xo.map(_ * 3)
None.map(i => "foo")
// Not this one
List(1, 3, 5).map(_ + 1) // removing the if guard completely also matches this
// The inner one
List(Some(1), None, Some(3)).flatMap(_.map(_ * -1))
// And from methods:
def foo: Option[Int] = Some(3)
foo.map(_ + 1)
```

I tried this:

```
if rcvr.tpe <:< typeOf[Option[_]]
```

Which works in the REPL (after `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._`), but in the plugin it throws an exception: "scala.ScalaReflectionException: class net.obrg.optionif.OptionIf in compiler mirror not found."

What is an appropriate if condition in the for loop to filter out any "map" on an expression that has been determined to be of type Option[_]?

Background: I'm trying to build a scala plugin that converts all `x.map(f)` expressions, where x is of type Option, to `(if (x.isEmpty) None else Some(f(x.get)))`.

The surrounding plugin boilerplate, so far:

```
package net.obrg.optionif

import scala.tools.nsc.{Global, Phase}
import scala.tools.nsc.plugins.{Plugin, PluginComponent}

class OptionIf(val global: Global) extends Plugin {
  import global._

  override val name = "optionif"
  override val description = "flattens map operations on options to if statements"
  override val components = List[PluginComponent](Component)

  private object Component extends PluginComponent {
    override val global: OptionIf.this.global.type = OptionIf.this.global
    // I'm not 100% on these constraints, but afaik these are appropriate outer bounds.
    // The typer phase is, obviously, necessary to determine which objects are of type Option, to begin with.
    override val runsAfter = List("typer")
    // The refchecks phase seems to do some if-related optimizations ("Eliminate branches in a conditional if the
    // condition is a constant"). So put it before this, at least.
    override val runsBefore = List("refchecks")
    override val phaseName = OptionIf.this.name
    override def newPhase(_prev: Phase) = new OptionIfPhase(_prev)

    class OptionIfPhase(prev: Phase) extends StdPhase(prev) {
      override def name = OptionIf.this.name
      override def apply(unit: CompilationUnit) {
        for (tree @ Apply(TypeApply(Select(rcvr, TermName("map")), typetree), List(param)) <- unit.body;
             if rcvr.tpe <:< definitions.OptionClass.tpe)
          {
            reporter.echo(tree.pos, s"found a map on ${rcvr} with type ${rcvr.tpe} and typelist ${typetree} and arg $param")
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Adapted from http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/140

EDIT: I just added the test for None.map(x => "foo") and the if guard actually *does* catch this! Still not the other ones, though.

Comment: Are you saying you have a classpath problem? It would help if you showed exactly how you compile and run, and the exception.

Comment: On the money, @som-snytt. I forgot to add .dependsOn(compilerPlugin) to the testproject, so it didn't have the plugin on its classpath. I didn't notice this because the plugin jar was referenced directly through an absolute path, so it "worked", but the class itself couldn't be found when using typeOf. If you put this comment up as an answer I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: You can just delete the question. "Didn't notice class not found" is probably a duplicate.